# how to get distinct values in mongodb using golang

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

I tried to retrieve a document from my collection  with unique id.

I have a collection with fields: name, age, city, and rank. I want to get 'city' results from mongodb using golang.

My struct code

```
type exp struct {
    name string `bson:"name"`
    age  int    `bson:"age"`
    city string `bson:"city"`
    rank int    `bson:"rank"`
}
```

With the following code to retrieve results from mongodb:

```
var result []exp //my struct type

err = coll.Find(bson.M{"City":bson.M{}}).Distinct("City",&result)

fmt.Println(result)
```

With this code I get an empty array as the result. How would I get all the cities?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this code

```
 var result []string 

 err = c.Find(nil).Distinct("city", &result)

 if err != nil {
     log.Fatal(err) 
 }

 fmt.Println(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Due to restrictions in reflection, `mgo` (as well as `encoding/json` and other similar packages) is unable to use unexported fields to marshal or unmarshal data. What you need to do is to export your fields by capitalize the first letter:

```
type exp struct {
    Name string `bson:"name"`
    Age  int    `bson:"age"`
    City string `bson:"city"`
    Rank int    `bson:"rank"`
}
```

A side note: you do not need to specify the bson tags if the desired name is the same as the lowercase field name. The **[documentation for `bson`](http://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson#Marshal)** states:

> The lowercased field name is used as the key for each exported field,
>   but this behavior may be changed using the respective field tag.

**Edit:**

I just realized you did get an *empty slice* and not a slice with empty struct fields. My answer is then not an actual answer to the question, but it is still an issue that you need to consider.